# Hide C# winform App Window When Started by Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, winforms, scheduled-tasks

I have searched google for this and read some resources but I wasn't able to find a good answer.
 Does anyone know how to prevent the winform App window from opening when it is started by the task scheduler?

Comment: Setting your main form's `Visible` to `false` should do the trick

Comment: @sallushan I believe OP wants to know if app was started by Task Scheduler or user.

Comment: Odd question, most programmers want to know how to make it *visible*.  The task scheduler runs programs using its own desktop by default.  Have you actually tried this or do you just assume it is going to be a problem?

Comment: @ Hans Passant I had tried it !

Comment: I have solved it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the form in the Shown event like this:

```
this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Shown);
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using command line arguments:

```
static class Program {

  [STAThread]
  static void Main() {
    if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains(@"/fromTask")) {
      // run something else...
    } else {
      Application.EnableVisualStyles();
      Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
  }
}
```

When you schedule your program in the Task Scheduler, be sure to include the argument `/fromTask`.

Comment: thank you .I have found a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background

Comment: @facebook-100002276297329 Your question didn't seem to be about *how* to use the Task Scheduler.

Comment: But that way could hide my pop up!Thx