# Run a batch file in a windows service

Tags: windows, service

I have a batch file, I want to run it as a windows service without using any additional software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Windows service from executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Comment: Are you sure you need to create a Windows Service? Most of the times creating a Scheduled Task does the job as well. Anyway what you ask is not possible since you will have to create an executable, so there will alsways be *additional software* involved.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Leo - Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding writing a good SO question.

Comment: I used sc.exe to create one but it threw an error saying that the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use any random application as a service, it has to be written explicitly for this purpose.

In your case it is better to just create a scheduled task but if you insist on creating a service you can download the [2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) and [use srvany.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/137890/how-to-create-a-user-defined-service). If you don't mind using 3rd-party tools you could try [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) instead.

Comment: here's how to make a sheduled task  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568736/how-do-i-set-a-windows-scheduled-task-to-run-in-the-background